# Dump Python sklearn model in Windows and read it in Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, scikit-learn, pickle

I am trying to save a sklearn model on a Windows server using sklearn.joblib.dump and then joblib.load the same file on a linux server (centOS71). I get the error below:

`ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling`

This is what I have tried:

1. Tried both python27 and python35
2. Tried the built in open() with 'wb' and 'rb' arguments

I really don't care how the file is moved, I just need to be able to move and load it in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Python pickle should run between windows/linux. There may be incompatibilities if:

1. python versions on the two hosts are different (If so, try installing same version of python on both hosts); AND/OR
2. if one machine is 32-bit and another is 64-bit (I dont know any fix so far for this problem)